# VScode cannot find chktex path and an error keeps popping up

Tags: pdftex, chktex

Everytime I try and compile my doc i keep getting the error that chktex could not be. I changed the folder to the be in C:\ but this made no difference.

Comment: Welcome to TeX StackExchange! It'd be great if you could edit your question to provide more details. For instance, could you paste the error message you're getting? Is chktex installed on your system?

Comment: This GitHub issue is old but have you set the `chktex` path similar to this: `"latex-workshop.chktex.path": "C:\\Program Files\\MiKTeX 2.9\\miktex\\bin\\x64\\chktex",` in your settings file? https://github.com/James-Yu/LaTeX-Workshop/issues/110